# Printing a document in C# best approach

Tags: c#, printing, .net-3.5, namespaces, wmi

am searching for a namespace in C# through which i can "**print and monitor printing**".Currently i used '**process**' to print a pdf ; But here i cannot monitor printing.Since process just throws document to printer.I went through Win32_Printer and System.printing both of them are dealing with "**controlling/monitoring print jobs**" but not **printing** a document.

How i print now:

```
ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
psInfo.Arguments = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["printer_name"];
psInfo.FileName = fileName;
psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psInfo.Verb = "print";
psInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
psInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process = Process.Start(psInfo);
```

what WMI does: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6592/A-simple-approach-for-controlling-print-jobs-using   and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394370.aspx

All i need to do is **check print status of a document i have printed at the moment**.Printed or not!!

Comment: In what way does a query for [`Win32_PrintJob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394370.aspx) not meet your needs? Or are you asking how to perform a WMI query from .NET code?

Comment: "Is it possible to print a document using Win32_PrintJob ?" is the doubt i have if yes pls provide link.. googling didnt help me!

Comment: Based on the list of methods on [`Win32_PrintJob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg196674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): no. You need an application that supports printing your document type: normally via using shell's file type registration & the print verb.

Comment: System.Printing namespace.  Won't help you, this is notoriously unreliable.  Good printers have lots of RAM, slurp the entire document in a fraction of a second and go about their business printing without reporting back.  You'll completely miss seeing it in the PrintQueue.

Comment: @ Richard ; @Hans Passant How can i go forward now? what is the good approach for "printing and getting status" of it in C# ?  Its Clear from both comments that i cannot use one or both namespaces for my requirement!